# Create many buttons at once

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'd like to create 64 buttons on a form using a For Loop

```
For i = 1 To 64
    Dim WithEvents B(i) As New Button
Next
```

But this code didn't work for me. Any ideas or methods to create several buttons at once ?!

Comment: You have to add the buttons to the Form (this is winforms right?), you can't just make new ones and do nothing with them. But if you want the buttons to do anything you will need to name them or at least `tag` them, and wire up click handlers. You should be able to Google how to add buttons to a Form programatically.

Comment: Also there are many examples here on SO that address this...

Comment: "any ideas" - Yes.  What you have presented indicates a near total lack of knowledge of the language and possibly programming concepts in general.  Start with reading the [Visual Basic Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh9ywfdk.aspx) to learn the basic language constructs.  Search for tutorials on programming.

Comment: ...then read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how SO works

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 64
        Dim btn As New Button
        btn.Text = "Button #" & i
        ' wire up the Click() event of the button:
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
        ' add the button to some kind of container...
        ' I 'm using a FlowLayoutPanel so I don't have to explicitly set a Location()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' cast the "sender" parameter to the source of the event:
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    MessageBox.Show(btn.Text & " clicked.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it :(
I'am just a beginner :)
This will create 64 buttons 
But how can i edit their size and text 
i tried the code but i didn't get 64 buttons 
would u please try to simplify the code
Thanks

Comment: There's an example of setting their text in there!...just set the `Text()` property.  To set the `Size()`, set the `Size()` property to something.  **What** exactly did you try?!  Update your original post above with your attempt at coding something so we can help you.

Comment: all what am looking for is a loop that will allow me to create 64 buttons instead of writing
Dim withevents B1,B2,........................B63,B64 As new button
is it possible using a for loop
sorry for bothering you

Comment: @ABK The answer contains the for loop you are looking for, in the `Button1_Click` event handler. This assumes that your form has a button named `Button1` which when clicked will add your 64 new additional buttons  to a container named `FlowLayoutPanel1`. These details can be changed depending on when and where you want these buttons created. Perhaps you could edit your question to tell us specifically where your button creation code needs to be located (constructor, event, etc.)? Because otherwise, this answer looks like it should do roughly what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks guys 
but i would like to control their location with another loop 
how can I manage to do it

Comment: ABK...you need to give SPECIFICS.  Of course you can set the location with a loop.  Here's an example: `btn.Location = New Point(10, i * 20)`.  Is that what you want?...probably not, but we have no idea what you are trying to do because you won't tell us.

Comment: Idle_Mind Thanks 4 the help u r really helpful
all what i'm looking for is to control the location, size,text of each button created 
for example 
btn1.text="thanks"
btn3.text="sorry"
btn43.size=new system drawing size (12,23)
btn45.location= new point (12.45)

Comment: @ABK If you can compute your controls' property values from the current loop iteration, then you should be able to set the `Text`, `Location`, `Size`, etc. property values using code [similar to this answer from another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16914448/3775798). But if you are going to use hard-coded values like your latest comment suggests, then you might either have to 1) use the loop control variable to access an item by index from a collection containing your predefined values, or 2) manually create all 64 buttons with the values you need for each one, with no loop.